# updating single item when using Angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am listing the elements from an array defined inside my controller on the view using `ng-repeat`. Each `item` has an edit and cancel button.

```
<div class="portlet-body" dir-paginate="item in keys>
  <div class="portlet portlet-blue">
    <div class="portlet-heading">
      <div class="portlet-title">
        <h4>{{item}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="portlet-body">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-disabled="textAreaDisable">{{baselineDataObj[item]}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="portlet-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="handleCancel()">Cancel
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="handleEdit()">{{editText}}
        </button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Inside my controller I have defined the function to update the button and disabling/enabling the text area:

```
$scope.textAreaDisable = true;
$scope.editText="Edit";

$scope.handleEdit=function(){
  if ($scope.editText === 'Edit'){
    $scope.textAreaDisable=false;
  } else if ($scope.editText === 'Submit'){
      console.log("came inside the Submit case ....");
  }
  $scope.editText = $scope.textAreaDisable? "Edit":"Submit";
}

$scope.handleCancel=function(){
  $scope.textAreaDisable=true;
    $scope.editText="Edit";
}
```

The functions `handleCancel` and `handleEdit` is applying on all the items, but I need to apply on the current element from which the function call is invoked. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: could you please show us the ng-repeat in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `handleCancel` and `handleEdit` functions and pass `item` as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Inside ng-click, you have access to a magical variable called $event, which you can pass to the controller functions. The $event parameter has a fair bit of info on it, like $event.target, which is the dom node of the target, you could use jquery, or angular.element($event.target) to then find the text area and enable it.

Conversely, you could pass a reference to the item itself, ng-click='handleEdit(item)' and adjust the controller functions to put the editing/cancelling flag on the item instead of the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `textAreaDisable` and `editText` properties to each item in the array. Right now they apply to all items.

Something like this:

```
$scope.items = [];
// initialize items array from server or wherever

for (var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++) {
   $scope.items[i].textAreaDisable = true;
   $scope.items[i].editText="Edit";
}
```

Then pass the item into the `handleEdit` and `handleCancel` functions:

```
$scope.handleEdit=function(item){
   if (item.editText === 'Edit'){
      item.textAreaDisable=false;
   } else if (item.editText === 'Submit'){
      console.log("came inside the Submit case ....");
   }
   item.editText = item.textAreaDisable? "Edit":"Submit";
}

$scope.handleCancel=function(item){
   item.textAreaDisable=true;
   item.editText="Edit";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways (according to me, maybe there are more).

- Pass complete item as parameter like `handleCancel(item)`
- Pass repeat index as parameter like `handleCancel($index)` and handle the array.
- Make use of the `$event` in the `ng-click` callback function

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using same scope variable for each ng-disabled for textarea.

here is an example. 
https://jsfiddle.net/q8r4e/1723/

```
$scope.keys = [
   {item : 'item01', input : '123', disabled : true , btnEdit : 'Edit'},
   {item : 'item02', input : '', disabled : true , btnEdit : 'Edit'},
   {item : 'item03', input : '', disabled : true , btnEdit : 'Edit'},
];
```